# Arrange div inside another div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**So if you have some free time:**

This is a quite complex thing, or I'm just too naive, as I've been working for hours without getting the desired output/result, I wish you could help me if you have some free time.

Firstly this is the data I have, which is retrieved from a PHP newsfeed, so is not a static number of items:

```
<span class="dateclass">date1</span>
<span class="dateclass">date2</span>
<span class="dateclass">date3</span>
....and so on
<br>
<div class="contentclass">content1</div>
<div class="contentclass">content2</div>
<div class="contentclass">content3</div>
....and so on
```

*I need to work with the classes and IDs, because is no php template engine so I can't call a single element, the code is distributed among several files, and the easier way to achieve what I need would be via javascript and their IDs / Classes*

I need to get the following output by copying the data above and, with Javascript, tweak the data in order to achieve the final result, which should be:

```
<div class="frame">
  <div class="timeline-badge"> <i class="fa fa-twitch"></i> </div>
  <span class="timeline-date"> <span class="dateclass">date1</span> </span>
  <div class="timeline-content"> <div class="contentclass">content1</div> </div>
</div>
<div class="frame">
  <div class="timeline-badge"> <i class="fa fa-twitch"></i> </div>
  <span class="timeline-date"> <span class="dateclass">date2</span> </span>
  <div class="timeline-content"> <div class="contentclass">content2</div> </div>
</div>
<div class="frame">
  <div class="timeline-badge"> <i class="fa fa-twitch"></i> </div>
  <span class="timeline-date"> <span class="dateclass">date3</span> </span>
  <div class="timeline-content"> <div class="contentclass">content2</div> </div>
</div>
```

*The `<div class="timeline-badge"> <i class="fa fa-twitch"></i> </div>` ones don't exist as data in order to "transform", yet those are part of the style and I'd need them as well, but I haven't gotten that far to actually worry about those :(*

I know, what a change!, yet I've been close to the result, I've been using different modified versions of the following code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("unique_ID");
  element.innerHTML = "";
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".contentclass"), function(e) {
    var example = element.appendChild(e.cloneNode(true));
  });
}, 300);
```

*I'm not posting all the versions I've made because none of them were going nowhere, and none of them work :/ I don't think I even have a copy of those*

So what I've tried unsuccessfully so far has been:

- Adding IDs to `<span class="timeline-date">` and `<div class="timeline-content">` so I can manipulate them with *js*
- Using a different `div` setups in order to achieve the final result by manipulating the *js* code, this means using the following div/HTML arrangement in order to paste the `cloneNode` results there with some added elements, such as `var div = document.createElement('div');` with `div.className += "frame";`, etc. Yet nothing works.
- I've tried adding an ID via javascript to a `div` created in the same code, something like this:

.....(a previously defined *variable* for counter, of course)

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = "id_frame"+counter;
counter++;
```

Yet it didn't work when I tried to send the results with `getElementById` and the ID generated with the `counter`

I'm about to give up, it has been quite complicated for me ;P ... Any suggestions? :(

As far as I could get was to something like this:

```
<div id="ID_unique">
  <div class="frame">
    <span class="timeline-date">date1</span>
  </div>
  <div class=" timeline-content">content1</div>
  <div class="frame">
    <span class="timeline-date">date2</span>
  </div>
  <div class=" timeline-content">content2</div>
  <div class="frame">
    <span class="timeline-date">date3</span>
  </div>
  <div class=" timeline-content">content3</div>
</div>
```

Which isn't actually that far from the final result if it wasn't for those `<div class="frame">` that should cover the *content* tags as well :(

Answer (score 1):

First thing i think you should do is get all `dateClasses` and `contentclass`, and then create your `frame` one by one:

```
var dateClasses = $('.dateClass'); // array of all your dateClasses
var contentClasses = $('.contentClasses'); // array of all your contentClasses

for(var i=0; i< Math.min(dateClasses.length,contentClasses.length); i++) {
     var frame = $("<div>", {class: "frame"}); // create your frame node
     var timeLineDate = $("<div">,{class: "timeline-date"});
     var timeLineContent = $("<div">,{class: "timeline-content"});

     //Append DateClass to your timeline-data:
     timeLineData.append(dateClasses[i]);

      //Append ContentClass to your timeline-content:
     timeLineContent.append(contentClasses[i]);

     //Append all to your frame
     frame.append(timeLineData);
     frame.append(timeLineContent);
}
```

I didnt run it or test it tough, but hope it will give you an idea on how to achieve what you want.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you for your time @yahyaelfakir Unfortunately I've been unable to make it work. By the way, I just added one fundamental thing to the main thread, and is that it is a newsfeed, so they aren't 3 or 5 classes, but X number of them, as they are retrieved via PHP... I need to workaround the IDs and Classes of the Div, I'm afraid...